# The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I got the error:

> error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

It  comes whenever I stop the IIS after a long time waiting for response in browser. If I am trying to wait then I got the error that `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` but the error I got who are written very old. I just write a new command who not got any exception. [I think the first run error got error first so all new error never can give exception].

So what I need to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The error means the connection pool is out of connections.  The usual cause is forgetting to close a connection after you use it, like:

```
var con = new MySqlConnection("Server=YourDB;Database=YourDb;...");
con.Open();
var com = con.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "select * from YourTable";
```

This code forgets to close the connection, so the pool has one less connection.  You could fix this by adding:

```
con.Close();
```

at the end.  But if the query throws an exception, the `Close` will be skipped, and you're still down 1 connection.

A much better way is the `using` statement:

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("Server=YourDB;Database=YourDb;..."))
{
    con.Open();
    var com = con.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandText = "select * from YourTable";
}
```

You can troubleshoot this easily by adding `max pool size` at the end of your connection tring, like:

```
Server=YourDB;Database=YourDbUid=YourUser;Pwd=YourPwd;max pool size=1;
```

This gives you a pool size of 1, instantly triggering an error condition if you forget to free up your one connection.

Comment: +1 Great suggestion about setting the pool size to 1 for debugging purposes.  That helped me a lot.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the current pool size?