# WCF using Nhibernate + Oracle fails to connect database intermittently

Tags: asp.net, wcf, nhibernate, oracle11g, timeoutexception

We have a 3 tier application developed using WCF. Our Web Layer [32 bit Windows 2003 Sp1] calls the WCF service [64 bit Windows 2008 R2 on an NLB] which communicates with the Oracle 10g DB [ 64 bit Linux ]. DB connection is established using Nhibernate 2.2. WCF communication uses BasicHTTPBinding.

In a 32 bit test environment application works well, but on the Live environment as specified above we experience crashes. As per the logging the repetitive error is,

System.ApplicationException :> Inner Exception being

> NHibernate.ADOException: While preparing select stderrorme0_.ERR_NO as
>   ERR1_10_, stderrorme0_.ERR_TYPE as ERR2_10_, .... ...., from
>   STD_ERROR_MESSAGE stderrorme0_ where stderrorme0_.ERR_NO=:p0 an error
>   occurred ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. 
>   This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and
>   max pool size was reached.

this error repeats, only that the table being fetched changes.

Temporary Solution: Restarting the WCF service hosted in IIS.

Please help us with your suggestions and solutions to get this to work. This post is raised after so many trial and errors following various blogs.

Comment: The most suspicious is *not* closed connection and/or *not* transaction see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642252/1679310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of connections not being disposed of properly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442062/221708), which in your case may be caused by not disposing of NHibernate sessions properly.  Just like you should wrap connections in `using` blocks, you should wrap NHibernate sessions in `using` blocks.

Here are a couple of good articles on managing NHibernate sessions in WCF:

- [NHibernate SessionPerRequest with WcfOperationSessionContext](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2011/03/30/nhibernate-sessionperrequest-with-wcfoperationsessioncontext/)
- [NHibernate session management and WCF, redux](http://richarddingwall.name/2011/04/22/nhibernate-session-management-and-wcf-redux/)

Also remember that if you are using the `sessionFactory.OpenSession(IDbConnection)` overload, you are responsible for closing the connection returned by `session.Close()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, we will definitely check in our nHib environment for such non-disposed objects. But what is confusing us is that the application works fine all our test environments. Only when deployed in the Live environment we have such a problem. So one doubt that I have is, could any database configuration or privileges be causing this..?

Comment: Perhaps live environment gets more traffic, meaning more connections to the DB?  Perhaps the test environment is deployed to more often, meaning more frequent WCF restarts?  It is definitely an issue with the WCF service not releasing DB connections since restarting it fixes the problem for a little while.